# Magento 2: How to add css in system config field

Tags: magento2, system-configuration

I need to add phtml file for the following path.

```
\app\code\Abc\Mkt\view\adminhtml\templates\validation.phtml
```

How do I add this?

> Validation.phtml

```
<?php $enable  = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('abc_auth/abc_settings/expiry_date');
$helper = $this->helper('Abc\Mkt\Helper\Data');
$expiry = $helper->checkExpiry();
if($enable == "failure" || $enable == "invalid" || $enable == "" || !$expiry ){ ?>
<style>
li.admin__page-nav-item.item._last{ display: none; }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where you want to add this phtml file ? Any particular section ?

Comment: Updated my comment. I need to add css for config section

Comment: @Shiwani, can u pls elaborate , its not cleared..

Comment: just need to add this CSS for admin config fields

Comment: You want to add css for system configuration fields, AM I RIGHT here ?

Comment: yes right, I need for system configuration fields

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: @Shiwani, I'm checking this at the moment and update you within 15 mins

Comment: Please check my answer. @Shiwani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100969/discussion-between-shiwani-and-kishan-savaliya).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create below files in your custom module to add your `validation.phtml` file in your custom module's system configuration. If you follow below steps then your validation file will not call in any other module's system configuration.

So first of all create `events.xml` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="custom_config_layout_load_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Adminhtml\LayoutHandler" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one `LayoutHandler.php` Observer file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Adminhtml/LayoutHandler.php

Content for this file is ..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Adminhtml;

class LayoutHandler implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http\Proxy $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $params = $this->request->getParams();

        if (! empty($params['section'])) {
            $moduleName = $this->getModuleName();
            if ($params['section'] == "custom_section_id") { //Here you can use your section ID which is available in your adminhtml/system.xml file's <section id='whatever'>
                $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
                $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('adminhtml_system_config_edit_section_custom_handler');
            }
        }
    }

    private function getModuleName()
    {
        $class = get_class($this);
        $moduleName = strtolower(
            str_replace('\\', '_', substr($class, 0, strpos($class, '\\Observer')))
        );
        return (string) $moduleName;
    }
}
```

- In above file, You just need to change your section ID in `if condition` like if I'm adding css for **General Configuration** then I'll use `general`, so you can use your custom module's system config's section ID here.

Now you need to create one layout xml file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit_section_custom_handler.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="custom_validation" template="Vendor_Module::system/config/validation.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

- Here I've included one `custom.css` **CSS** file and one template file called `validation.phtml`.

So you need to create above both files in this location..

**CSS**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/custom.css

**phtml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/validation.phtml

You can add whatever content here based on your requirement.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Yes am checking and update you

Comment: Did you tried this ?

Comment: just checking. gimme 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

You can set class in the field by `<frontend_class>` tag. Like this below code:

```
<field id="country_id" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
    <label>Country</label>
    <frontend_class>countries</frontend_class>
    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
</field>
```

Reference: `vendor/magento/module-shipping/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`